# Why is it that my data is being truncated while uploading an csv file in my database?

Tags: mysql, csv

Im trying to upload data to my contacts table by importing an csv file. My csv file contains just data, i have removed the column titles.

And my csv looks like this:

[image]

Im trying to import it by going to localhost phpmydamin and importing it in a table by browsing this file. Im using utf-8 and my format is CSV using LOAD DATA.

When click on continue i have the following errors:

```
Error Code: 1265. Data truncated for column 'id' at row 1 
Row 1 does not contain data for all columns
```

I get the errors above for several rows.

This is my create table in mysql:

```
CREATE TABLE `contacts` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `position` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `mobile_no` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `mobile_no2` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `descriptionMobile` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `descriptionMobile2` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

csv data in notepad:

```
1,30 de Agosto TV Color - Miguel Angel de Arrieta,de Arrieta,x,NULL,NULL,Movil,Movil,MdeArrieta@30deagosto.com.ar,1
2,"Banda De Frecuencia 4G LTE Banda 4  1700 MHz Banda 7 2600 MHz Banda 28 700 MHz, Celulares",4G LTE Banda 4  1700 MHz,x,NULL,NULL,Movil,Movil,NULL,1
3,A Beneficio CONABIP,A,x,NULL,NULL,Movil,Movil,abenef@conabip.gov.ar,1
4,AAATesters,AAATesters,x,NULL,NULL,Movil,Movil,orders2@aaatesters.com,1
5,Aaron Isaac Gonzalez,Aaron Isaac,x,1134432558,NULL,Movil,Movil,NULL,1
6,"Aaronia AG,Germany",Aaronia,x,4.97E+12,NULL,Movil,Movil,mail@aaronia.de,1
7,ABA GAS GNC,ABA GAS,x,1122598905,11-4572-3900 ::: 11 6382-7811,Movil,Movil,NULL,1
8,abel cortez,abel,x,NULL,NULL,Movil,Movil,NULL,1
9,Abel Curin,Abel,x,NULL,NULL,Movil,Movil,NULL,1
10,Abogada John Maria Jauregui,Abogada John,x,NULL,NULL,Movil,Movil,abelcor86@yahoo.com.ar,1
11,Abogada Silvina Corazza VIAVI,Abogada Silvina,x,1147536648,NULL,Movil,Movil,abelcurin@mymcom.com.ar,1
12,Abogado Jose M�ndez Marcas Y Patentes,Abogado Jose,x,1147324171,11-474-712-44,Movil,Movil,NULL,1
13,Abogado Multas Infracciones,Abogado,x,54108184,549108184,Movil,Movil,scorazza@clarkemodet.com.ar,1
14,Abonados vtcc,Abonados,x,1150084093,NULL,Movil,Movil,mendezacostaJo@gmail.com,1
15,ACA Automovil Club Argentino,ACA,x,1132696543,NULL,Movil,Movil,NULL,1
16,ACA Nro Socio,ACA Nro Socio,x,NULL,NULL,Movil,Movil,abonados@vtcc.com.ar,1
17,Acontece SRL,Acontece SRL,x,NULL,NULL,Movil,Movil,administracion_seguros@aca.org.ar,1
18,Adan Solian,Adan,x,1144509164,(011) 4458-3194,Movil,Movil,acontec@acontec.com.ar,1
19,Adela Liebhardt,Adela,x,NULL,NULL,Movil,Movil,actv@iverde.dataco33.com.ar,1
20,Adema,Adema,x,NULL,NULL,Movil,Movil,asolian@cybercom-cw.com.ar,1


LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\\xampp\\tmp\\phpF39A.tmp' INTO TABLE `contacts` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ENCLOSED BY '\"' ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

Any reason while im getting this errors?

Comment: Add sample rows from the csv file as text, add table definition as text, add load data infile code as text, confirm row terminator.

Comment: how can i do all of these things? @P.Salmon

Comment: Open csv file in a text editor eg notepad copy and paste to question, show create table <tablename> from phpmyadmin copy and paste result to question, copy and paste load data infile command used to question.

Comment: Done i think @P.Salmon, i edited the question

Comment: Did You use LOAD DATA INFILE if so need to see the code.

Comment: I do not know if i used LOAD DATA INFILE @P.Salmon is there any way to tell if i used it?

Comment: Did you use an import wizard then?

Comment: Okey, no i did not use import wizard, is used CSV as LOAD DATA, columns separated by ";", and columns enclosed by between " @P.Salmon How can i get the code of the LOAD DATA INFILE on phpmyadmin?

Comment: LOAD DATA INFILE expects you to provide all columns (including defaulted columns) your csv files is 2 short - see manual how to specify columns to be loaded..

Comment: So should i also add to my csv columns as created_at and updated_at? @P.Salmon

Comment: The first column it is for id indeed, and why should my second column be bigint if it is a name field i created it as varchar? I also added the LOAD DATA INFILE code to my question @P.Salmon

Comment: You are being disingenuous your table definition before the last edit included a bigint customerid as the second column..

Comment: Thats because i pasted a wrong table definition, that one was the old one @P.Salmon

Comment: You could try the **CSV Lint** plug-in for Notepad++ https://github.com/BdR76/CSVLint to check any errors in the CSV file. Or use the `Convert to SQL` option and just run that as a script to insert all data.

Answer (score 1):

As describe in the manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html you can specify map the columns to be loaded

so loading the first 4 rows..

```
drop table if exists t;
CREATE TABLE t (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `position` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `mobile_no` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `mobile_no2` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `descriptionMobile` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `descriptionMobile2` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
);
load data infile
'C:\\Program Files\\MariaDB 10.1\\data\\csv.txt'
into table t
columns terminated by ','
optionally enclosed by '"'
lines terminated by '\r\n'
(   `id`,
  `name` ,
  `lastname` ,
  `position` ,
  `mobile_no` ,
  `mobile_no2`,
  `descriptionMobile`,
  `descriptionMobile2`,
  `email`,
  `status` 
 )
;

select * from t;
+----+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+----------+-----------+------------+-------------------+--------------------+------------------------------+--------+------------+------------+
| id | name                                                                                      | lastname                 | position | mobile_no | mobile_no2 | descriptionMobile | descriptionMobile2 | email                        | status | created_at | updated_at |
+----+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+----------+-----------+------------+-------------------+--------------------+------------------------------+--------+------------+------------+
|  1 | 30 de Agosto TV Color - Miguel Angel de Arrieta                                           | de Arrieta               | x        | NULL      | NULL       | Movil             | Movil              | MdeArrieta@30deagosto.com.ar |      1 | NULL       | NULL       |
|  2 | Banda De Frecuencia 4G LTE Banda 4  1700 MHz Banda 7 2600 MHz Banda 28 700 MHz, Celulares | 4G LTE Banda 4  1700 MHz | x        | NULL      | NULL       | Movil             | Movil              | NULL                         |      1 | NULL       | NULL       |
|  3 | A Beneficio CONABIP                                                                       | A                        | x        | NULL      | NULL       | Movil             | Movil              | abenef@conabip.gov.ar        |      1 | NULL       | NULL       |
|  4 | AAATesters                                                                                | AAATesters               | x        | NULL      | NULL       | Movil             | Movil              | orders2@aaatesters.com       |      1 | NULL       | NULL       |
+----+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+----------+-----------+------------+-------------------+--------------------+------------------------------+--------+------------+------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Using ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

The first 13 rows do load even with the dubious character in row 12

```
drop table if exists t;
CREATE TABLE t (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `position` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `mobile_no` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `mobile_no2` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `descriptionMobile` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `descriptionMobile2` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
load data infile
'C:\\Program Files\\MariaDB 10.1\\data\\csv.txt'
into table t
columns terminated by ','
optionally enclosed by '"'
lines terminated by '\r\n'
(   `id`,
  `name` ,
  `lastname` ,
  `position` ,
  `mobile_no` ,
  `mobile_no2`,
  `descriptionMobile`,
  `descriptionMobile2`,
  `email`,
  `status` 
 );
 
 select * from t;
+----+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+----------+------------+-------------------------------+-------------------+--------------------+------------------------------+--------+------------+------------+
| id | name                                                                                      | lastname                 | position | mobile_no  | mobile_no2                    | descriptionMobile | descriptionMobile2 | email                        | status | created_at | updated_at |
+----+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+----------+------------+-------------------------------+-------------------+--------------------+------------------------------+--------+------------+------------+
|  1 | 30 de Agosto TV Color - Miguel Angel de Arrieta                                           | de Arrieta               | x        | NULL       | NULL                          | Movil             | Movil              | MdeArrieta@30deagosto.com.ar |      1 | NULL       | NULL       |
|  2 | Banda De Frecuencia 4G LTE Banda 4  1700 MHz Banda 7 2600 MHz Banda 28 700 MHz, Celulares | 4G LTE Banda 4  1700 MHz | x        | NULL       | NULL                          | Movil             | Movil              | NULL                         |      1 | NULL       | NULL       |
|  3 | A Beneficio CONABIP                                                                       | A                        | x        | NULL       | NULL                          | Movil             | Movil              | abenef@conabip.gov.ar        |      1 | NULL       | NULL       |
|  4 | AAATesters                                                                                | AAATesters               | x        | NULL       | NULL                          | Movil             | Movil              | orders2@aaatesters.com       |      1 | NULL       | NULL       |
|  5 | Aaron Isaac Gonzalez                                                                      | Aaron Isaac              | x        | 1134432558 | NULL                          | Movil             | Movil              | NULL                         |      1 | NULL       | NULL       |
|  6 | Aaronia AG,Germany                                                                        | Aaronia                  | x        | 4.97E+12   | NULL                          | Movil             | Movil              | mail@aaronia.de              |      1 | NULL       | NULL       |
|  7 | ABA GAS GNC                                                                               | ABA GAS                  | x        | 1122598905 | 11-4572-3900 ::: 11 6382-7811 | Movil             | Movil              | NULL                         |      1 | NULL       | NULL       |
|  8 | abel cortez                                                                               | abel                     | x        | NULL       | NULL                          | Movil             | Movil              | NULL                         |      1 | NULL       | NULL       |
|  9 | Abel Curin                                                                                | Abel                     | x        | NULL       | NULL                          | Movil             | Movil              | NULL                         |      1 | NULL       | NULL       |
| 10 | Abogada John Maria Jauregui                                                               | Abogada John             | x        | NULL       | NULL                          | Movil             | Movil              | abelcor86@yahoo.com.ar       |      1 | NULL       | NULL       |
| 11 | Abogada Silvina Corazza VIAVI                                                             | Abogada Silvina          | x        | 1147536648 | NULL                          | Movil             | Movil              | abelcurin@mymcom.com.ar      |      1 | NULL       | NULL       |
| 12 | Abogado Jose Mï¿½ndez Marcas Y Patentes                                                   | Abogado Jose             | x        | 1147324171 | 11-474-712-44                 | Movil             | Movil              | NULL                         |      1 | NULL       | NULL       |
| 13 | Abogado Multas Infracciones                                                               | Abogado                  | x        | 54108184   | 549108184                     | Movil             | Movil              | scorazza@clarkemodet.com.ar  |      1 | NULL       | NULL       |
+----+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+----------+------------+-------------------------------+-------------------+--------------------+------------------------------+--------+------------+------------+
13 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

That's not to say that the csv file does not contain other unhelpful artefacts.

Comment: Please augment your example by specifying `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4` -- assuming that the file is encoded UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be already bad:

```
Abogado Jose M�ndez
```

See "black diamond" in [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)

That link also talks about "truncation", which is another symptom of inconsistent configuration in MySQL UTF-8 data.

If possible, get a hex dump of the word with a mangled character.  Also, try to get `SELECT HEX(col), col...` from the database table.  Both of these will help with getting to the bottom of the problem.

It may be useful to use `chcp 65001` in the Windows run window.